# WebView automatically zoom in after first change of scale

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a WebView and i load an image into it. If image is bigger than phone's screen i want to zoom out to have all image on the screen. I do this using WebView.LoadFinished EventHandler. When LoadFinished is triggered i calculate scale to zoom out and set as WebView's MinimumZoomScale and ZoomScale. It works fine but after first zoom in or zoom out image automaticaly zoom in to some specific scale and i can't zoom out. How can i solve it ?

```
    private void InitializeWebView()
    {
        WebView.ScalesPageToFit = true;
        WebView.LoadFinished += WebView_LoadFinished;
    }

    private void WebView_LoadFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var contentSize = WebView.ScrollView.ContentSize;
        var viewSize = View.Bounds.Size;
        var scale = viewSize.Width / contentSize.Width;

        WebView.ScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = scale ; //removing this makes that my image doesnt zoom out after loaded
        WebView.ScrollView.ZoomScale = scale ;
    }

    public void LoadAttachment(string fileName)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            return;
        }

        var documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var targetUrl = documentsPath + "/" + fileName;
        var url = new NSUrl(targetUrl);

        if (url != null)
        {
            var request = new NSUrlRequest(url);
            WebView.LoadRequest(request);
            //Example request: "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6BDB8CD2-280B-45A3-9109-8E08E1314739/Documents/26112018110204.jpg"
        }
    }
```

I try use Lucas Zhang - MSFT's solution like this:

```
    private void WebView_LoadFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var contentSize = WebView.ScrollView.ContentSize;
        var viewSize = View.Bounds.Size;
        var scale = viewSize.Width / contentSize.Width;

        WebView.ScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = scale;
        WebView.ScrollView.ZoomScale = scale;

        NSString str = new NSString($"var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.content='width=device-width,initial-scale={1.0},minimum-scale={scale},maximum-scale={WebView.ScrollView.MaximumZoomScale}';meta.name='viewport';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);");
        WebView.EvaluateJavascript(str);
    }
```

Screenshots:

[Image opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VjYr.jpg)

[Image scrolled right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcFTp.png)

[Image after first zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv7lo.png)

It is not visible but on the third screenshot there is still posibility to scroll image right. Not all image is on the screen.

Comment: Hey ,did you solve the problem?

Comment: No, not yet. Your solution makes that image is full screen after loaded and it is ok but there are a lot of black space on the right and below the image. It wasn't before adding your code. After the first change of scale it is better, zoom is smaller but still all image is not presented and i have to scroll.

Comment: Can you provide some screenshot?

Comment: I have edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**
Because you didn't refer to the tag `meta` in your html file.

**Solution:**
Add the following code in the method `WebView_LoadFinished`

```
private void WebView_LoadFinished(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var contentSize = WebView.ScrollView.ContentSize;
    var viewSize = View.Bounds.Size;
    var scale = viewSize.Width / contentSize.Width;

    WebView.ScrollView.MinimumZoomScale = scale ;
    WebView.ScrollView.ZoomScale = scale ;

    NSString str = new NSString("var meta = document.createElement('meta');meta.content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=2.0';meta.name='viewport';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);");
    webView.EvaluateJavascript(str); 
}
```

> minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=2.0

You can set the value of MinimumZoomScale and MaximumZoomScale here.